# KeyCloak - reuse session when one Realm is and IDP for another

Tags: keycloak, idp

I'm using KeyCloak version `21.1.1` and basically I'm implementing a scenario where one Realm (`Main Realm`) is used as and IDP for another Realm (`Aux Realm`).
I implemented this according to documentation and indeed, when logging in to `Aux Realm` there is a button allowing to authenticate using the configured OIDC provider which is actually the `Main Realm` and the authentication works. The missing part of the puzzle is how can I allow a user that belongs to `Main Realm` access resources in `Main Realm` after he logged in through the `Aux Realm`, using `Main Realm` as and IDP provider. Intuitively it feels that it should be possible to attach to the existing session on `Main Realm`, but I can't figure out a way of doing this.